# Matching Columns with Overlapping Intervals (lubridate)

Tags: r, tidyr, lubridate

I have two data frames of different number of rows and number of columns: each of these data frames have a date interval. df has an additional column which indicates some kind of attribute. My goal is to extract information from df ( with the attributes) to df2 under certain conditions. The procedure should be the following:

For each date interval of df2, check if there is any interval in df which overlaps with the interval of df2. If yes, create a column in df2 which indicates the attributes matching with the overlapping interval of df. There can be multiple attributes that are matched to a specific interval of df2.

I created the following example of my data:

```
library(lubridate)
date1 <- as.Date(c('2017-11-1','2017-11-1','2017-11-4'))
date2 <- as.Date(c('2017-11-5','2017-11-3','2017-11-5'))
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=3, ncol = 4)) 
names(df) <- c("Begin_A", "End_A", "Interval", "Attribute")
df$Begin_A <-date1
df$End_A <-date2

df$Interval <-df$Begin_A %--% df$End_A
df$Attribute<- as.character(c("Attr1","Attr2","Attr3"))

### Second df:

date1 <- as.Date(c('2017-11-2','2017-11-5','2017-11-7','2017-11-1'))
date2 <- as.Date(c('2017-11-3','2017-11-6','2017-11-8','2017-11-1'))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=4, ncol = 3)) 
names(df2) <- c("Begin_A", "End_A", "Interval")
df2$Begin_A <-date1
df2$End_A <-date2
df2$Interval <-df2$Begin_A %--% df2$End_A
```

This results in these data frames:

df:

```
Begin_A      End_A        Interval                         Attribute
2017-11-01   2017-11-05   2017-11-01 UTC--2017-11-05 UTC   Attr1
2017-11-01   2017-11-03   2017-11-01 UTC--2017-11-03 UTC   Attr2
2017-11-04   2017-11-05   2017-11-04 UTC--2017-11-05 UTC   Attr3
```

df2:

```
Begin_A      End_A        Interval
2017-11-02   2017-11-03   2017-11-02 UTC--2017-11-03 UTC
2017-11-05   2017-11-06   2017-11-05 UTC--2017-11-06 UTC
2017-11-07   2017-11-08   2017-11-07 UTC--2017-11-08 UTC
2017-11-01   2017-11-01   2017-11-01 UTC--2017-11-01 UTC
```

My desired data frames look like this:

```
Begin_A      End_A        Interval                         Matched_Attr 
2017-11-02   2017-11-03   2017-11-02 UTC--2017-11-03 UTC   Attr1;Attr2
2017-11-05   2017-11-06   2017-11-05 UTC--2017-11-06 UTC   Attr1;Attr3
2017-11-07   2017-11-08   2017-11-07 UTC--2017-11-08 UTC   NA
2017-11-01   2017-11-01   2017-11-01 UTC--2017-11-01 UTC   Attr1;Attr2
```

I already looked into the int_overlaps() function but could not make the "scanning through all intervals of another column"-part work.
If yes, is there any solution that makes use of the tidyr environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tidyverse´s lubridate package and it´s function `int_overlaps()`, you can create a simple for loop to go through the individual values of `df2$Interval` like follows:

```
df2$Matched_Attr <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  df2$Matched_Attr[i] <-  paste(df$Attribute[int_overlaps(df2$Interval[i], df$Interval)], collapse=", ")
}
```

giving the following outcome

```
#     Begin_A      End_A                       Interval Matched_Attr
#1 2017-11-02 2017-11-03 2017-11-02 UTC--2017-11-03 UTC Attr1, Attr2
#2 2017-11-05 2017-11-06 2017-11-05 UTC--2017-11-06 UTC Attr1, Attr3
#3 2017-11-07 2017-11-08 2017-11-07 UTC--2017-11-08 UTC             
#4 2017-11-01 2017-11-01 2017-11-01 UTC--2017-11-01 UTC Attr1, Attr2
```

I left the NA strategy open, but additional line `df2$Matched_Attr[df2$Matched_Attr==""]<-NA` would return exact desired outcome.

In response to your comment (only perform the above action when a df$ID[i]==df2$ID[i] condition is met), the inplementation follows:

```
library(lubridate)
#df
df <- data.frame(Attribute=c("Attr1","Attr2","Attr3"),
                 ID = c(3,2,1),
                 Begin_A=as.Date(c('2017-11-1','2017-11-1','2017-11-4')),
                 End_A=as.Date(c('2017-11-5','2017-11-3','2017-11-5')))
df$Interval <- df$Begin_A %--% df$End_A

### Second df:
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(3,4,5),
                  Begin_A=as.Date(c('2017-11-2','2017-11-5','2017-11-7')),
                  End_A=as.Date(c('2017-11-3','2017-11-6','2017-11-8')))
df2$Interval <- df2$Begin_A %--% df2$End_A

df2$Matched_Attr <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  if(df2$ID[i]==df$ID[i]){
  df2$Matched_Attr[i] <-  paste(df$Attribute[int_overlaps(df2$Interval[i], df$Interval)], collapse=", ")
  }
}
print(df2)
#  ID    Begin_A      End_A                       Interval Matched_Attr
#1  3 2017-11-02 2017-11-03 2017-11-02 UTC--2017-11-03 UTC Attr1, Attr2
#2  4 2017-11-05 2017-11-06 2017-11-05 UTC--2017-11-06 UTC         <NA>
#3  5 2017-11-07 2017-11-08 2017-11-07 UTC--2017-11-08 UTC         <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! Can I adapt the aforementioned procedure to a case in which I have another (character) column along which I want the loop to run? Let's say the new column in both df and df2 is called "ID" and I only want to run the procedure if the ID matches?

Comment: What kind of matching do you mean exactly? Can you give a short example? If df2ID[1] == df$ID[1] then calculate the Matche_Attr ? Or something similar?

Comment: Yes. "If df2ID[1] == df$ID[1] " is the condition. In a dplyr setting I would have just used group_by(ID) but I do not know how to translate this to our loop used here.

Comment: I see, its definiely possible, I will update my answer later today aiming at the condition you described.

Comment: I added an answer to the second question from the comment